# "Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code" in Xcode 11.0 beta

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode11, ios13

I am using Xcode 11.0 beta and since two days I am stuck on this error. half of the project is built on SwiftUI.. I wonder if this is the reason that the error is coming...

I have tried restarting my Mac, deleting derived data, building and cleaning the project,  updating the pods

I think think this problem is caused by SwiftUI

Comment: You're saying something wrong in Swift and it's crashing the Swift compiler. You need to focus on what it is. Can't help you because you've shown zero code.

Comment: If you click on the error, it should give you more info (highlighted in red). If you can share that info here, you might get more help.

Answer (score -2):

It usually tells you the reason when you click on it you can read about your problem , maybe a file is deleted or missing . 
or if no logical reason was found , clean build your project it'll be ok . don't worry .